# Differences between Political ideologies

Tags: ideology

What is the basic difference between Anarchism & Communism?

Comment: This is way *too broad*

Comment: I will not write your Government 101 final exam essay for you.

Comment: There is Anarcho-Communism by the way.

Comment: Hello user258458, welcome to Politics.SE; in this place, we have some techniques to write a question with some details. You didn't take the [Politics.SE Tour](http://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), please take and then come back to rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2):

Marxist Communism and Anarchism both claim in the future desired society there will be no state. Anarchism calls to weakining and abolishment of the state as an instrument of exploitation, while Communism claims the state will disappear through its strenghtening.

Comment: Is there anything else you want to share ?

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer. Very succinct, although obviously a vast oversimplification. If you want more information than a really basic answer like this, there are heaps of books out there.